# CONCAT together with IF ELSE?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id`             int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `academicdegree` varchar(255),
  `name`           varchar(255),
  `firstname`      varchar(255),
  `sex`            enum('m','f')
)
```

```
SELECT TRIM(CONCAT_WS(" ", firstname, name)) AS fullname FROM users
```

Is there a way to add a useful salutation (Mr. or Mrs.) according to the `ENUM` value stored in the field "sex" in just one query?

**Bonus track:**
*I only can replace this part of the query: `TRIM(CONCAT_WS(" ", firstname, name))` and `;` is not allowed.*

Comment: There are multiple titles for each gender. How would you choose the correct one?

Comment: @a'r I will add them to the query "by hand". For this example `m = "Mr." and f = "Mrs."` will be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work just fine:

```
SELECT TRIM(CONCAT_WS(" ", IF(sex='m', 'Mr.', 'Mrs.'), firstname, name)) AS fullname FROM users
```

You could use a `CASE` statement, however if you've only got two options an `IF()` statement makes more sense.

Comment: @ean5533 Thanks, but that's no reason to delete your perfectly good answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TRIM(CONCAT_WS(" ", CASE sex WHEN 'm' THEN 'Mr.' WHEN 'f' THEN 'Mrs.' ELSE '' END, firstname, name)) AS fullname FROM users
```

(Note: this differs from the other answers in that it won't assume that a null `sex` implies `'Mrs.'`. Though personally I'm not sure that even `sex = 'f'` should really imply `'Mrs.'`, since that salutation is normally not used for unmarried women, at least below a certain age.)

Comment: thanks for the note! But I will change the code to german (Herr/Frau) anyway ;-)

Comment: @powtac: O.K., that makes more sense. :-)